# How can I filter time by using Django_Filters

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
start_time = django_filters.TimeFilter(lookup_expr='gte', field_name='created_at__hour', input_formats="%H")
end_time = django_filters.TimeFilter(lookup_expr='lte', field_name='created_at__hour', input_formats="%H")
```

Input: start_time = 10

Result: {
"start_time": [
"Enter a valid time."
]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you filter on the `__hour` lookup, these are integers, so you filter with:

```
start_time = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='gte', field_name='created_at__hour')
end_time = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='lte', field_name='created_at__hour')
```